# Limit UDP to subdomain only

Tags: udp, subdomain, reverse-proxy, minecraft

I have a Minecraft Bedrock server running on Docker, using the default port of 19132.

I'd like to limit access to *only* `mc.domain.com:19132`

Currently `domain.com:19132` (on the same IP) is also functional.

How can I limit access to only the subdomain?

I use Nginx for reverse proxying webtraffic, and the server is hosted with DigitalOcean.

Thanks.

Comment: Do these domains have different IP addresses?

Comment: They're both on same IP - will amend question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I limit access to only the subdomain?

TL;DR: You want to limit access based on information which are not available on the server. This is impossible.

Given that both domains share the same IP address and [the protocol](https://wiki.vg/Pocket_Minecraft_Protocol) does not include the target domain name either, it is impossible to distinguish the traffic between the two domains on the server side. Only the client knows which domain name was used to access the server, the server sees only the IP address and this is the same for both domains.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Are you aware of any 3rd party services that can installed on the server that can see the domain requested, and  then provide the necessary routing?

Comment: @MikeThrussell: Again, there are not enough information to do the routing on the server. No third party services installed on the server can change this since they too don't have the necessary information.  These information are solely at the client side. If you want to distinguish UDP traffic for different domains on the server side you need different IP addresses for these domains.